# date search from date picker cannot pass to the controller

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

This is my code it prints date but not the date from the date picker search it just output today's date not the date search in the date picker:

Here is my input field:

```html
<input type='text' readonly id='search_fromdate' class="datepicker" placeholder='From date'>
<input type='text' readonly id='search_todate' class="datepicker " placeholder='To date'>
<input type='button' id="btn_search" value="Search">
```

Ajax:

```js
var dataTable = $('#emp-table').DataTable({
  'ajax': {
     'url':url,
       'data': function(data){
          var from_date = $('#search_fromdate').val();
          var to_date = $('#search_todate').val();
          data.searchByFromdate = from_date;
          data.searchByTodate = to_date;
     }
  },
```

and this is my controller:

```php
public function qTime(Request $request){
    $from_date = '';
    $end_date =  '';
    $from = Carbon::parse($request->searchByFromdate)->toDateString();
    $to = Carbon::parse($request->searchByTodate)->toDateString();
```

Comment: Please see updated code with field @sta but there is no problem with the field the problem is why it cannot be get from the controller

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the object in your `data` (check the docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Something like this should do the trick

```js
var dataTable = $('#emp-table').DataTable({
 'ajax': {
   'url':url,
   'data': function(data){
      return {
        searchByFromdate: $('#search_fromdate').val(),
        searchByTodate: $('#search_todate').val(),
      }
   }
 },
```

Comment: does not fix the problem but thank you for your answer.

Comment: could you check and show us what you are getting in either `$request->toArray()` on php side or what is sent in the network request?

Comment: nice :D What are you sending in the request? (network tab)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it is not `$request->toArray()` but `$request->all()`

Comment: error also when i get that using
$from = Carbon::parse($request->searchByFromdate)->toDateString();
this returns the current date.